# An upper bound on the least common multiple of the first $2n+1$ integers

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $a, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$ p^a \mid \operatorname{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n+1) \implies p^a \leq 2n + 1 \implies a \leq \dfrac{\ln(2n+1)}{\ln p}$$

and

$$\operatorname{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n+1) \leq \prod_{\{p \mid p \leq 2n+1 \text{ and $p$ is prime}\}}p^{\dfrac{\ln(2n+1)}{\ln p}} $$

I have already proved the first statement, but I'm unsure of how I can use that to prove the second statement.

Comment: The $\operatorname{lcm}$ is the product of powers of the primes $\leqslant 2n+1$. So if you have the bounds for the exponents, that's it.

Comment: There is less to this than meets the eye. Let $p^{b_p}$ be the largest power of $p$ that divides our factorial. Then $(2n+1)!=\prod_{p\le 2n+1} p^{b_p}$. But $b_p\le \frac{\log(2n+1)}{\log p}$.